# curl - post request send file from link

Tags: php, curl

Is it possible to send a link of file instead of content in curl post request ?

```
$file_to_upload = array('file_contents'=>'@'.$file_name_with_full_path);
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$target_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $file_to_upload);
$result=curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
echo $result;
```

can I put a link instead of $file_name_with_full_path ?

Comment: This is a copy and paste form http://blog.derakkilgo.com/2009/06/07/send-a-file-via-post-with-curl-and-php/ ??? Why did you not test it first ??? I knew have see this code before

Comment: Because at the moment I can't test! You're smart that you knew about code!!! I think u write it here just to show how you are smart, I just write copied to have an answer to my another question! @Baba

Answer (score 0):

You can use temp file for that.
Example: http://php.net/manual/en/function.tmpfile.php#69419